# using \enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want to use

```
\begin log-file
\begin{enumerate*}[(i)]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc 
\end{enumerate*}
\end log-file
```

It doesn't work. Do I need some special packages?
I use the following packages

```
\begin log-file
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\end log-file
```

Comment: You need to have `\usepackage{enumerate}` in your preamble for this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what `\begin log-file` is, but if what you are looking for is an inline list you can use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}`:

[image]

If you wish to use the old style `\begin{enumerate*}[(i)]` then you need the `shortlabels` option:

```
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}‎‎‎‎
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc 
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}‎
```

---

### Code: `shortlabels`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}‎‎‎‎
\begin{enumerate*}[(i)]
  \item The first item
  \item The second item
  \item The third etc 
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}‎
```